# How to make the condition false if (.) is found

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c#. I am trying to build the calculator in c#. Everything is working fine and decimal point system is working fine too but my main problem is I don't want decimal to repeat more than once. Currently If I put 0.1 + 0.1  i will get 0.2 .But I want to stop the decimal point once its being use just like calculator.  I did put the condition in constructor to be `isDecimal = false` and creating new number after that. So it will recognize the and fail the condition. Can someone help me out what I am doing wrong please. Thank you. Please try to give simple explanation so that I can understand and also I am fairly new

```
using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calc
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a constructor which will run atleast once. This will also create new number 
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        memory = 0;
        txtResult.Text = "0";
        t = 0;
        h = 0;
        count = 0;

        //boolean Type
        isDecimal = false;
        creatingNewNumber = true;  // saying we we want to create the new number
    }
    private double leftSide;
    private bool creatingNewNumber;
    private double rightSide;
    private double memory;
    private string operators;
    private double t;
    private double h;
    private double count;
    private bool isDecimal;

    /// <summary>
    /// A function to add two numbers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Left Side of an addition</param>
    /// <param name="y">Right Side of an addition</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the answer to the addition.</returns>
    public double add(double x, double y)
    {
        //do sdome work
        leftSide = x;
        rightSide = y;

        double z = leftSide + rightSide;

        return z;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Function to add substract
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Left Side </param>
    /// <param name="y">Right Side</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the answer in substraction</returns>

    public double substract(double x, double y)
    {
        leftSide = x;
        rightSide = y;

        double s = leftSide - rightSide;

        return s;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to call the multiply
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Left side</param>
    /// <param name="y">Right Side</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the value in multiplication</returns>
    public double multiply(double x, double y)
    {

        leftSide = x;
        rightSide = y;

        double m = leftSide * rightSide;

        return m;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// function to call the division and also stating that if the number on right is 0 throw an error.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Left Side</param>
    /// <param name="y">Right Side</param>
    /// <returns>Return the value in division</returns>
    public double divide(double x, double y)
    {
        double d;
        leftSide = x;
        rightSide = y;

        if (rightSide == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by zero");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            d = leftSide / rightSide;
        }
        return d;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The function does division. In addition what it does is store the memory value in y and 
    /// then at last it creates the conditional value wheather to create new value or to append
    /// the value when the operator is press which is (+-*/)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void divide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   // divide
    {
        bool StillOK = true;
        double y;
        if (!double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, out y))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Right Side is not a valid number");
            StillOK = false;
        }
        if (StillOK)
        {
            memory = y;
            operators = "/";
            creatingNewNumber = true;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The function does division. In addition what it does is store the memory value in y and 
    /// then at last it creates the conditional value wheather to create new value or to append
    /// the value when the operator is press which is (+-*/)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void multiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // multiply function
    {
        bool StillOK = true;
        double y;

        if (!double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, out y))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtResult.Text + " is not a valid number");
            StillOK = false;
        }
        if (StillOK)
        {
            memory = y;
            operators = "*";
            creatingNewNumber = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The function does division. In addition what it does is store the memory value in y and 
    /// then at last it creates the conditional value wheather to create new value or to append
    /// the value when the operator is press which is (+-*/)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // add function
    {
        bool StillOK = true;
        double y;
        if (!double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, out y))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtResult.Text + " is not a valid number");
            StillOK = false;
        }
        if (StillOK)
        {
            memory = y;
            operators = "+";
            creatingNewNumber = true;

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The function does division. In addition what it does is store the memory value in y and 
    /// then at last it creates the conditional value wheather to create new value or to append
    /// the value when the operator is press which is (+-*/)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void substract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // substract function
    {
        bool StillOK = true;
        double y;

        if (!double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, out y))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtResult.Text + " is not a valid number");
            StillOK = false;
        }
        if (StillOK)
        {
            memory = y;
            operators = "-";
            creatingNewNumber = true;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This function resets the Txt Result box to zero
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // clear function
    {

        memory = 0;
        txtResult.Text = "0";
        creatingNewNumber = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This Function will focus on decimal Point 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //decimal point                   ( . ) 
    {
        if (isDecimal)
        {
            txtResult.Text = ".";
            isDecimal = true;
            creatingNewNumber = true;

        }
        txtResult.Text += "."; // should add one more decimal point 
    }


    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double equal;
        if (!double.TryParse(txtResult.Text, out equal))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtResult + "This is not an valid.");
        }
        else
        {
            switch (operators)
            {
                case "+":
                    memory = add(memory, equal);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    memory = substract(memory, equal);
                    break;
                case "/":
                    memory = divide(memory, equal);
                    break;
                case "*":
                    memory = multiply(memory, equal);
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }

            txtResult.Text = memory.ToString();  // convert text to string result 
            creatingNewNumber = true;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ? Any suggestion will be welcome. Thank you for your help

Edit: right now I can click 0..1 I am trying to block that and only want to display 0.1 ( no more . should be allow after . is being used)

Comment: What do you mean you want to "stop using the decimal point like a calculator". If you're getting 0.2 from 0.1 + 0.1, what's wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by `I want to stop the decimal point once its being use just like calculator`. This just doesn't make sense. Why would you want to stop the decimal point? It is no how calculators work

Comment: Oh, do you mean your next calculations are also being considered decimal? Can't you just after `creatingNewNumber = true;` set `isDecimal = false;`?

Comment: If i press . it should only use one time but right now in my program if i keep pressing "." it will press as many time as i press but i want I have made the code or trying to do is once "." is press user cannot press again or it will not let it appear again on calculator

Comment: So you don't want user to enter '0..1'?

Comment: @Dispersia in my code i did do that.

Comment: @bc004346 yes that is correct, that is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You can try to capture keys and do some decisioning on which `KeyCode` to allow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/q/2108616/215552

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need all this in your decimal block here

```
private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    if (isDecimal)
    {
        txtResult.Text = ".";
        isDecimal = true;
        creatingNewNumber = true;
    }
    txtResult.Text += "."; // should add one more decimal point 
}
```

Should be something like this

```
private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    if (txtResult.Text == string.Empty || txtResult.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        return;
    txtResult.Text += "."; 
}
```

NOTE: I see that other answers here will tell you something about text validation, key press events and so - you need none of this in regards to text box. All form key presses should be directed to button clicks. Text box should be read-only and once you disable any direct keyboard-to-text box entry, all you will need is to check that if you press button with ".", if the dot is already there, bypass.

Comment: There is no calculator where the textbox is read-only. Even the default windows one allows you to manually edit. And this solution DEFINITELY will not work. He states his string will be like `0.1 + 0.1`, right now, this will force him to have `0.1 + 01`.

Comment: If you press .2 the number will automatically start with new number which is 2 and . will be erase . Also quick question how come you not returning anything ?

Comment: @Dispersia please, don't even start on this one. You can't set focus in Win Calc. when you press the button, the form catches the key and a routine assigned to specific button runs. It is a custom draw box (if you wish to call it that way) but not just a text box where you input things

Comment: @Seth this is language feature. `return` is used with value in method that returns value and in a `void` you use it without value to say *"I want to exit method"*. If you press ".2" the code I posted prevents "." because you need to supply some digit first, "0" for example. Once you supplied one or more digits, you will be able to see "." and after this you will not be able to put in more "."

Comment: so how can you solve that problem. I see lot of regex but i m learning so i dont understand regex. I like your solution

Comment: @Seth you don't need any regex for calculator. Just control input via available input options. In your case these options are the buttons on your form. don't let direct input into the text box. Preview the key on the form and call corresponding `button_click`. Although, this is not most efficient way, it will get you going. You should really play with key up/down and play with button pics. Start small. wire all buttons to same event and check what button that is to add to text box accordingly. Use `button.Performclick` to invoke. so, it will sound like `if (key == 5) button5.PerformClick`.

Comment: You can copy paste into it windows calculator perfectly fine. Your solution -WILL NOT WORK- in that scenario, nor ANY scenario as he describes it as `0.1 + 0.1`

Comment: IDK, looks like windows calculator handles a paste event by parsing the clipboard one character at a time and simulating keypresses (e.g. try pasting 0.01 + 0.01).  The rest of the OP's code implies that the textbox cannot contain symbols, only the most recent number, and limiting that number to one decimal point by controlling input is probably the best solution.

Comment: @Dispersia again, any actions that you do to win calc are done on the level of Form key preview. If form intercepts `ctrl+v`, clipboard being read, parsed etc. you don't have to use regex. All you need is `double.TryParse` on clipboard value and that will tell you if it is valid or invalid, or numerical text

Comment: No, it doesn't. It doesn't even use Windows Forms. And open the Event Log, you can literally try it yourself. You are wrong. (it doesn't use regex, no, however it does a stack based parse, which double.TryParse will not do. Notice, you can literally copy 0.1 + 0.1 into it. Stop making things up). It does a stack based iteration off of the text that is inputted into the box. The only thing that the button does is add to the string value.

Comment: @Dispersia a person is trying to write first program. Why are you getting into this stuff? Meanwhile, too bad you still believe that the control used in win calc is a text box. Paste `0.1 + 0.1`? No problem.  still works with intercepting `ctrl+v` and parsing the expressions. I can use `double.TryParse` each individual part.. This is not the point. Point, for simple calc the OP can simply learn how to do `textbox.Text += ...` based on pressed button. After all, OP is not building copy of win calc

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this kind of text validation is with a regular expression:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

where
`^` means "start of string"
`[0-9]+` means "1 or more numbers" (`[...]` indicates a character class - i.e. a choice of characters)
`$` means "end of string"
`\.` means a literal period (normally, `.` would mean "any character at all" - the backslash indicates that it's an alternate meaning than the "usual" meaning)
`?` means "0 or 1 times" (i.e. the decimal part is optional, but if they have it it can only appear once)

Some examples of invalid inputs that this would catch:

- .1
- 1.
- 1...2
- 1.2.3

Comment: I want to display like 1.3 + 0.3  = 1.6

Comment: no text validation needed for calculator. Text box should be modified when specific buttons are pressed

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I found the answer and zero does include. **Updated Code**

```
 if (creatingNewNumber == true)
        {
            if (txtResult.Text.IndexOf('.') == -1)
            {
                creatingNewNumber = false;
                txtResult.Text += ".";
            }
            else
            {
                txtResult.Text = "0.";
                creatingNewNumber = false;
            }
```

Comment: this is exactly what my answer is. Only inverted

Comment: Learning regex is nice but not needed for this project. You missing the point. your issues come from incorrect design. you're new to this, you will learn eventually. Read my comments under my answer. especially my answers to  "dispersia". the pains you have now will go away in a year or two. Also remember, there are lot of people here who will send you in a wrong path. Look for people with high reputation earned by answering many same language questions. there are people with 10K points, with 8K of them earned from same question.

Comment: Reputation has absolutely nothing to do with the validity of someone.

Comment: I still havent solve the issue. It only works one side but after the operator is being pressed it willl not work. It works one way not after button been press

Comment: Have you tried my solution? (or EJoshuaS, but his would take a bit to implement based on your current implementation)

Comment: @Seth you need to solve simple issues like this one. If we solve it for you, you will miss on opportunity to think and create

Comment: Finally I did it and now its working perfect and flawless. I dont know, if i m missing anything else. Feel free to let me know if any error is found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you show the mathematical operations or just the final result, but if you show the full operation in the text box (e.g; 5 + 1.2 = 6.2), the following may help you to make some validations on the text changes:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lastOperatorIndex = ((TextBox)sender).Text.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '*' });

        lastOperatorIndex = lastOperatorIndex < 0 ? 0: lastOperatorIndex + 1;


        // Check if the new added character is '.' and the if last number has already a decimal point then prevent the change.
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Last().Equals('.') &&  ((TextBox)sender).Text.Substring(lastOperatorIndex, textBox1.Text.Length - lastOperatorIndex - 1 ).Contains('.'))
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have it as textBox1_TextChanged, you don't need to cast sender back to get the text, you do it on the set but on your gets you cast it everywhere. Just a small note.

Answer (score -1):

Add a TextChanged event to your Input. In your TextChanged event, add

`myInput = new Regex("[.]{2,}", RegexOptions.None).Replace(myInput, ".");`

This will handle while user is typing, if they copy paste, and will blanket cover any time they try to handle ".".

To make it handle nicely for the user, simple caret control could be used:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentCharIndex = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    Regex r = new Regex("[.]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);

    if (r.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
    {
        textBox1.Text = r.Replace(textBox1.Text, ".");
        if(textBox1.SelectionStart > 0)
            textBox1.SelectionStart = currentCharIndex - 1;
    }
}
```

(warning, this may be inefficient for very large string inputs, but for what you're doing it for it should handle it just fine).

EDIT: If you're clicking buttons it will remove focus, fixed so that it will only do it if the index is greater than 0 (it's 0 if no focus or at the beginning)

Comment: no text validation needed for calculator. Text box should be modified when specific buttons are pressed

Comment: Yes it still is. When you push the button, it will add the text to textBoxResult. textBoxResult is then replaced with the output when the "=" button is pressed. If you do the validation on the textbox, it will prevent them from copy-pasting, etc, incorrectly. There are plenty of calculators that allow you to manually edit the text field. Even the Windows one does.